# How to pass arrays from C++ to assembler dll?

Tags: c++, assembly

I would like to pass 4 arrays from c++, 2 arrays are 2D and 2 arrays are normal. I have this code in c++:

```
typedef int(*DLLFunc)(double**, double*, double**, double*, int);
```

//main and some other code

```
hDll = LoadLibrary("FibAsmLib");

    if (hDll != NULL){

        myAsmProc = (DLLFunc)GetProcAddress(hDll, "MyProc");

        if (myAsmProc != NULL){
            result = myAsmProc(arrayA, arrayB, arrayAlfa, arrayBeta, rowA);
        }
        cout << "Result from library: " << result;
    }
```

and this in assembler:

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall
.data
.code

PUBLIC MyProc
MyProc proc w: DWORD, x:DWORD, y:DWORD, z:DWORD, e:DWORD
mov eax, 5
ret
MyProc endp
end
```

When i run program I have strange error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You told your assembler that the exported procedure adheres to the stdcall calling convention, but the C program thinks it's cdecl (if you don't specify a particular calling convention VC++ assumes cdecl). Fix either side and the problem should go away.

Comment: thank you, your advice was very helpful
this is correct line:
typedef int(_stdcall *DLLFunc)(double**, double*, double**, double*, int);